# Is it possible to create function-static objects programmatically?

Tags: c++

I need to create a vector which holds the pointers to some static objects (e.g., a1, a2, a3).

```
void foo()
{
    static TEST a1, a2, a3;
    static vector<TEST *> m_test;
    m_test.push_back( &a1 );
    m_test.push_back( &a2 );
    m_test.push_back( &a3 );
}
```

But I don't want to have to write out the declaration for each `static` object.

How can I use a loop to do this? I have tried something like:

```
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        m_test.push_back( &(static TEST()));
    }
```

But it seems the `static` doesn't have any effect inside an expression, as the objects get destroyed, as I'd expect from a normal temporary.

Comment: How does this manifest itself?  Show the code that produces unexpected behavior.

Comment: I'm surprised that even compiles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function-static objects may only be created by a defining declaration with a name. You can't create a "function-`static` temporary" like that.

How about:

```
static const size_t N = 10;
static TEST tests[N];

for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   m_test.push_back(&tests[i]);
}
```

Otherwise, you have no option but to resort to dynamic-storage objects, the only objects whose very existence in any given scope can be controlled programmatically (not least because they're not *really* in any scope at all). In fact, this is pretty much *the* use case for objects of dynamic storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless your static objects are stored in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Will this be good for you?

```
void foo()
{
    static TEST t[10];
    static vector<TEST *> m_test;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        m_test.push_back( &(t[i]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring the `TEST` objects individually, declare a `vector` of `TEST` objects:

```
void foo()
{
    static vector<TEST> a(3);
    static vector<TEST *> m_test(3);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        m_test[i] = &a[i];

    // Of course, now you may discover that you didn't 
    // need "m_test" after all, you could just use "a"
}
```